Cannot connect to postgres 16 remotely
I think I have exhausted everything I can think of. Using postgresql 16
If I try to connect with

psql -d dbname -h localhost

it prompts for a password and connects just fine. However, if I try to connect with

psql -d dbname -h 192.168.86.27

it does not prompt for password and I get this message

psql: error: connection to server at "192.168.86.27", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.86.27", user "postgres", database "dbname", no encryption

My pg_hba.conf contains this
local   all             all                                     trust
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       trust
host    all     all     ::0/0   trust
host    all     all     192.168.0.0/16      trust

My postgresql.auto.conf contains
listen_addresses = '*'

netstat -nlt shows that the ports should be accepting all connections
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN 

I realize the security implications of setting it up this way. I'm just trying to get it to work at this point.

The netstat output is unnecessary; you already know that the postgres server is accepting the connection (and responding with an error message regarding access control).

I can't reproduce this behavior. I set up this test environment, and once it's running I can psql -h 192.168.86.27 -U postgres and connect without errors.

Are you /sure/ that [that specific] configuration is being used?
There is no entry in there that would prompt for a password!
"trust" just lets you in.  The likes of "md5" would start asking for a password.

That's what I mean. It all makes no sense. It shouldn't prompt for a password, but does. It should allow through every connection, but it definitely does not.
The netstat output was included to show that the listen_address was working correctly.

I have pg_hba down to 2 lines now
//host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust//
//host    all             all             ::0/0                   trust//
Without specifying host to psql, works without password. Specifying localhost prompts for password. Specifying IP gets error (no prompt for passwod).
I'm looking at pg_hba.conf in /usr/local/pgsql/data ($PGDATA). I am looking at the wrong file?

I think I found the issue. I was working with the wrong pg_hba.conf file. The one in the PGDATA directory (/usr/local/pgsql/data) is the incorrect one. The real file is in /var/lib/pgsql/16/data.
I modified that file and it appears to be working correctly now.
